# How do I debug a visual studio project in IIS instead of IIS express?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

This deals with the "debug in web browser" button specifically.
[image: button image]

I can debug a running project by clicking "attach to process" and that works... sort of.  It does not allow us to debug javascript or html inside visual studio, and that is what we want to do.  Currently we are forced to debug in the web browser's tools, and that is less than ideal.

We are using visual studio 2017 community.

Each of our dev computers has a cloned client database on it.  Publishing locally to that works fine.  What i would like to happen is that the debug (play) button ALSO hook to that database.  Currently it is creating a new blank database in IIS.  I am positive this is possible, but i do not know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting answer is silly.  The main connection string in the project needed to point at the sql database, and that's it.  We alias it out for each client, but evidently the run button doesn't do the aliasing.